# Prevent repeating root nodes or child nodes of root nodes using inputted directories

Tags: c#, treeview, treenode

I was wondering how could I prevent the repetition of a root node or child nodes within that root node? As well as any child nodes of a child node etc. Keep in mind these nodes are based off inputted directories (I don't want to use Directory.GetDirectories or anything).

For example, if I inputted these three things:

> cat\dog\monkey
>
> cat\dog\tree
>
> cat\dog\tree\monkey

Then the TreeView would look like this:

```html
cat 
  dog
    monkey
    tree
      monkey
```

I know this task may seem really easy, and for all I know it could be, but for some reason, I find it quite hard to do this. I also need to easily be able to associate the last node of each inputted directory with an object. So for example, "tree" would have data associated with it, etc. The process should be usable as many times as I like, in case I later decide to input more directories into the TreeView.

Thanks!

Edit: Figured it out.

Comment: How are these nodes created? Is someone manually creating them? Do you only need to perform this check when adding new nodes, to ensure that the value doesn't appear in any of its parents? Do any of the nodes already have children when you add them, or are single nodes with no children added one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

1. split your input
2. get count of every args
3. check if there is already existing node on certain dimension
4. add or skip

example code looks like this. (This code may not be optimized code)

```
string[] input;
int count = input.Count;
getinput(input);
TreeNode CurrentNode = new TreeNode("Root");
this.treeview1.Add(CurrentNode);
foreach(string[] inputVal in input) {
    foreach(string[] sp in inputVal.Split('\\')) { 
        CurrentNode = this.treeview.FindNode("Root");
        for(int i = 0; i<sp.Count; i++) {
            bool findSign = false;
            foreach(TreeNode TN in CurrentNode.ChildNodes) {
                //find if current node contains node named with sp[i]
                if(TN.Text == sp[i]) {
                    findSign = true;
                    CurrentNode = TN;//set Current node as found node
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(findSign == false) {
                //if node name wasn't found, add a new node on current node
                TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(sp[i]);
                CurrentNode.Add(newNode);
                CurrentNode = newNode;//add node and set as current
            }   
        }
    }
}
```